# How to replace numbers in cells with names from a list in a loop in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, replace

In my continuing quest for making an easier job out of organizing an on-call schedule for my work place, I've hit another roadbump.

I got really great help with arranging a numbered schedule before that looks like this:

[Picture of numbered schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4FDm.png)

Each of those numbers correspond to a specific name on the list in green to the right called "Personal".

Now I want to substitute those numbers with the names on the green list with a loop.

I tried doing it like this, by selecting the range of cells with the numbers and then making a loop to replace all individual numbers with the names in the list:

```
Sub FindReplaceAllTest(numOfEmployees As Integer)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Integer
Dim rplc As Variant

fnd = 1
rplc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duty Roster").Cells("17, fnd + 1").Value

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Range("B2:F54").Select
    Selection.Replace What:=fnd, replacement:=rplc, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

    If fnd < numOfEmployees Then
        fnd = fnd + 1
    ElseIf fnd = numOfEmployees Then
        fnd = 0
    End If

Next sht

End Sub
```

The variable `numOfEmployees` is gathered in an earlier SUB where the names in the green list are counted and passed on into this variable, this for the sake of the process of creating the numbered list.

Unfortunatly it doesn't yield the desired results. I get error '1004' at the line:

```
rplc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duty Roster").Cells("17, fnd + 1").Value
```

This seems to be caused by the `fnd` variable in that line. When i take out `fnd` and replace it with a regular row reference I get a result like this:

["Fnd" switched out for "2": "rplc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duty Roster").Cells("17, 2").Value"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqaOn.png)

Even though I put "2" in the row I still get the name of the list as a substitute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct sintax is the following

rplc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duty Roster").Cells(17, fnd + 1).Value

Which will get you the value of cell in column "fnd+1" and row 17

Furthermore you're looping through sheets but never actually use them since you neither use "sht" nor prefix any range object with a "dot" to refer it to the "ruling" sht. Like follows:

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

```
sht.Range("B2:F54").Replace What:=fnd, replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Comment: Thank you! With Your pointers I found out what I really wanted to say and do! I changed my code to look like this to provide the desired results (check below, I listed it in a new entry).

Answer (score 0):

Coming from this:

[Schedule before numbers been replaced by the green list of employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3JQb.png)

This code:

```
Sub FindReplaceAllTest(numOfEmployees As Integer)

Dim n As Integer
Dim fnd As Integer
Dim rplc As String

fnd = 1

    Do Until n = numOfEmployees + 1

        rplc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Duty Roster").Cells(fnd + 1, 17).Value

        Range("B2:F54").Select
        Selection.Replace What:=fnd, replacement:=rplc, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False,_
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

        n = n + 1
        fnd = fnd + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Produced these results:

[Schedule after numbers been replaced by the green list of employees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMY0W.png)

Many thanks to user3598756 for providing me with what I needed to solve this! She/He pointed out that I was writing parts in my code I did'nt need so I switched out my `For Each Loop` with a `Do Until Loop` and also replaced the `sht` variable with `n` (and rewrote them according to my needs) to make it work. He also made me aware that I had mixed up the placement of the column/row references. After editing that as well my code started producing the results I wanted.

So what my code now does is to compare the variable `n` with the variable `numOfEmployees + 1` to make sure the loop stops when `n` > than `numOfEmployees`. Making sure all numbers are included. Furthermore the loop looks at `fnd` within my designated range and switching out all instances of that number with the value in the cell found at the variable `rplc`.

That's my (I hope correct, I'm fairly new to this) simplified answer to what I've done.

Thanks a bunch for the help!